# How do I use a private trait from another module?

Tags: rust

I am trying to run the following snippet:

```
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::sys_common::AsInner;

fn main() {
    let ip: Ipv4Addr = Ipv4Addr::new(127,0,0,1);
    println!("{}", ip.as_inner().s_addr);
}
```

This fails with

```
test.rs:3:5: 3:29 error: trait `AsInner` is private
test.rs:3 use std::sys_common::AsInner;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.rs:7:20: 7:33 error: source trait is private
test.rs:7     println!("{}", ip.as_inner().s_addr);
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:25: 2:56 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 2:62 note: in expansion of print!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:58 note: in expansion of println!
test.rs:7:5: 7:42 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I do see that the `AsInner` trait is private in http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/src/std/net/ip.rs.html#238
How do I use the trait?

Edit:
I was trying to convert an Ipv4Addr to an int, I thought I could read the underlying in_addr. But it seems using the octets is a better idea.

Comment: You cannot. The whole idea of private things is that they cannot be used outside of the module they are defined.

Comment: Why do you need the `AsInner` trait?

Comment: I agree with @DanielFath - now that this question has been answered with resounding certainty, perhaps you should ask another question and try to avoid [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (if applicable).

Comment: I was trying to convert an `Ipv4Addr` to an int, I thought I could read the underlying `in_addr`. But it seems using the octets is a better idea. Thanks for replying everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vladimir Matveev said it best:

> You cannot. The whole idea of private things is that they cannot be used outside of the module they are defined.

Comment: Thanks, I added some explanation about what I'm trying to do.